# Typescript - Read CSV column by column

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv, csvreader

I am trying to read csv in typescript column by column.

The csv is like below:

```
Prefix,Suffix
Mr,Jr
Mrs,Sr
```

Based on few SO questions and typescript documentation, I am able to read from file like:

```
public readConfig() {
    const results: any[] = [];

    fs.createReadStream('D:/NameConfig.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data: any) => results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
            return results;
        });
}
```

But, this reads the entire csv. I am unable to save the individual columns like Prefix and Suffix as individual array. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

I have consumed the columns like below and have that added in a list and retrieved later.

```
public readConfig() {
    fs.createReadStream('D:/NameConfig.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data: any) => {
            prefixList.push(data["PREFIX"]);
            suffixList.push(data["SUFFIX"]);
        });
}
```